# Interpretation of Tensor Flow CNN results with big dips in accuracy while training

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I am trying to classify images using a CNN in tensor flow. I am doing 10 fold cross validation. At each fold, the training set is 900+ images and the validation set is 100 images. It is only two classes.
I am having a hard time interpreting the results graph when I plot by epoch. As you can see, accuracy seems to go up, but between 140-165 epochs it dips very much, and then again toward 300 epochs. This is happening on each fold. Here are two graphs (two folds) as an example.

How should I interpret this?
Thank you.
[image: Accuracies for fold 5]

[image]

Setting up, these are the layers (each function will then load them).

```
   def add_convolutional_layers(self):
        # Two sets of convolutional layers
        for idx in range(0, 2):
            if idx == 0:
                self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10, (5, 5), input_shape=(
                self.size, self.size, 3)))  # todo: only works for color images
            else:
                self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(40, (5, 5)))
            self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
            self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"))
            self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        # Output shape: 40 x 61 x 61
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

    def add_hidden_layers(self):
        # TODO: In Mathematica, Dropout[] has a rate of dropping 50% of elements then * by 2 -- ours does not.
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5, seed=self.seed))

        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation="linear",
                                             activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                                             kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05)))

        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation="relu",
                                             activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                                             kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05)))

        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25, seed=self.seed))

    def add_output_layers(self):
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,
                                             activation="linear",
                                             activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                                             kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05)))
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,
                                             activation="softmax",
                                             activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                                             kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05)))
```

Then, the parameters of the CNN are:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.lr,
                               beta_1=0.9,
                               beta_2=0.999,
                               epsilon=0.00001,
                               # decay=0.0,
                               decay=0.00001,
                               amsgrad=False)
self.model.compile(optimizer=opt,
                   loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: how is your architecture and what optimizer are you using?

Comment: The optimizer is Adam. Architecture:it's a Sequential() model with these layers:

1. Conv2D

2. BatchNormalization

3. Activation

4. MaxPooling

5-8: repeat 1-4

9: Flatten

10: Dropout

11: Dense

12: Dense

13: Dropout

Output layers:

14: Dense(2) linear

15: Dense(2) softmax

Comment: you probably have large learning rate

Comment: The learning rate is 0.00001. Should I go a few orders of magnitude lower?

Comment: It always depends on the problem, but it's quite low (speaking generally). Can you post your code & data as well? + did you standardise your data?

Comment: Just added the code. The images passed are 256x256 color.

Comment: What does a plot of the gradient magnitude look like? My hypothesis is that the gradient becomes large, so the model abruptly moves out of the high-quality region, and then progresses back towards it.